# Docker: Curl errors when attempting to contact app in same container

Tags: php, curl, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I've got some problems with Docker and cURL.

I have a Docker-compose container set as follow:

```
app:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /home/ben/dev/dummy/www/:/data/www/
    - /home/ben/dev/dummy/logs/:/data/logapache/
    - /home/ben/dev/dummy/flux-entrants/:/data/flux-entrants/
nginx:
  image: docker.dummy.fr/nginx
  volumes_from:
   - app
  ports:
   - 80:80
  links:
   - php
php:
  image: docker.dummy.fr/actus-php
  volumes_from:
   - app
  ports:
   - 9000:9000
  links:
   - db
   - nosql
db:
  image: docker.dummy.fr/mysql-5.6
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
nosql:
  image: docker.dummy.fr/lp-nosql
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
```

There are also extra_hosts directive which I have removed here for confidentiality reasons, but the hosts are configured also in nginx (mapped to port 80 of course) and in the containers /etc/hosts

So, the nginx, php, mysql and elasticsearch are all in separate containers. The **nginx container** is linked to the **php container** who links to the other two.
This works just fine, and no problem with that in particular.

Inside these containers I run **two web apps**, as seen with the extra hosts: one **frontend client** (Symfony 2.8), and a **backend API** (also Symfony 2.8).

***Now to the problem.***

When I try to contact the **API app** from outside the **php container**, typically Postman, or cURL cli from my terminal on my linux, or cURL from the **nginx container**, no problem.

But when the **front app** (in the same container) attempts to contact the **API app**, or when I try to curl from inside the **php container**, I get cURL errors "Connection refused". Verbose mode shows that the header aren't even sent.

I thought it was a port mapping problem, but changing the ports, openning new ones and attempting to connect via these ports doesn't work either.

I tried contacting it via port 9000 (used for nginx upstream and openned in the docker-compose), but then I get another error: "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer". Verbose mode shows that headers and request are properly sent, then the server drops the connection.

Has anyone already had this issue? If yes, how did you resolved it? I searched here but couldn't find the same problem.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

I just tried making two separate sets of containers (one PHP container + one Nginx container) for each app (front and API), mounting separately each app in its own containers, and I still got the same issue. I just can't understand.

Comment: Not clear from inside of what container you try to establish what connection via cURL? What is API for you? Also please attach output of docker ps with running containers.

Comment: I have four containers, including one solely for php (named php in the docker-compose).
Inside this container live two distinct Symfony apps: a front client app, and a back/API app.
Whe I cURL the API app from my terminal, from Postman or whatever outside the php container, everything works. When the front attemps to call the API, or when I attemp to cURL the API from inside the php container, it doesn't work.

Comment: could you provide your cURL command and the output of "docker ps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that requests from the **php container** to itself weren't getting out, hence not passing by the **nginx container** who could properly dispatch them.

We finally used a quick fix by using the symfony command `php app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:80` into the **API app** (inside **php container**). Basically, we started a second php server, having then one server for each app, allowing them to communicate properly.

A proper fix and (imo) better design would have been to merge the **nginx and php containers** into a single one. Having separate containers for the server and the databases seems legit, but having separate containers for the server and for the interpretor leeds to too many problems.